# Highstock Navigator always starts from date 1970-1-1

Tags: highcharts

The data is imported by csvURL and sorted in reverse.

```
data: {
    csvURL: 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/FSE/VOW3_X.csv?api_key=FaKetdwzkQQPhX91Xrhx',
            parsed: function(data) {
            var name;
            data.forEach(function(column) {
            name = column.shift();
            column.reverse();
            column.unshift(name);
             });
              },
    switchRowsAndColumns: false,
    firstRowAsNames: true,
    startRow: 0,
    endRow: 4000,
    seriesMapping: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 4
        },
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}]
}
```

Unfortunately the navigator always starts with the date 1970-1-1: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/04Lu2bpa/1/

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248564/highstock-navigator-always-starts-from-1970-1-1 ?

Comment: Do you want to display just the close series? It seems that this seriesMapping array breaks it. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ej7qmk8u/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes, I only want to display the close series. In your example all series are displayed. Is there a way to select the close series without the navigator bug?

Comment: It seems like the rest of your data breaks the chart and if you don't want to change the data the only solution which came to my mind is cleaning the unwanted arrays.
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hzkfb8m2/

Comment: That did it. Thank you!